# How to play a video file (avi/mp4) in AppleTV?

Tags: itunes, video, appletv

Suppose I would like to play a video file (avi/mp4) in AppleTV 3. I see two options:

- play the file in the laptop and mirror the screen via AirPlay on the AppleTV.
- import the file into the ITunes in my laptop connected to my home network, enable home sharing, and make AppleTV play this file from the ITunes.

Is it correct ? Are there *easier* ways to play a video file in a laptop in AppleTV ?

Comment: Thanks, I would like to stream the video _wireless_ to my AppleTV connected to a TV with an HDMI cable

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to to stream it via AirPlay.

You could also use a cable to hook up your TV, or stream it from an iDevice. You could also put in on a supported video stream site (like YouTube), and play it from the Apple TV's app. There are more ways then I'm able to list in the answer, so explore!

Answer (score 2):

But I don't think itunes support avi file since all Apple device only accepts .mp4, .mov and .m4v videos. You'd better convert avi to mp4 or other Apple supported video format before straming via AirPlay.